# Send an array from Javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I would like to send array to the server.

This is how i try to send the array:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "file.php",
        datatype : "json",
        data : JSON.stringify({ name: "Daniel", phone: "01234123456" }),
        success: function(msg){ 
            alert('Success!');
        }
    });
});
```

This is how i try to get the array in file.php

```php
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_GET);
print_r(json_decode($_POST);
```

Of course in the firebug console i see the array but not on the page.

Comment: How are you testing this? _i see the array but not on the page_.

Comment: BTW you never print the result on to the screen - you have to, in the success callback function, add them to the DOM, otherwise they will not just apear there by magic

Answer (score 0):

You are currently sending the data - what you refer to as the 'array' in the format of JSON - java script object notation.

It is not possible to send data across (at least in jQuery ajax) in JSON. You must stringify it before you send it, and then decode it in the php end (like you already do - got that part right). You would have to do something like:

```
  data: JSON.stringify({ name: "Daniel", phone: "01234123456" }),
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: jQuery [does this automatically](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) by default. If `data` contains an object, it will be urlencoded and the request header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` will be set. In OP's case the data would already be available in `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['phone']` in PHP.